# How to merge/partial update on sub document which is an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    projectId: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true },
    company: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required: true },
    description: { type: String, trim: true },
    remark: { type: String, trim: true },
    active: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    participants: [{
        user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
        active: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        timeSpent: [{
            date: { type: Date, required: true },
            hour: { type: Number, required: true }
        }]
    }]
});
```

I've searched through a lot of SO questions, but none of them seems to be able to solve my problem. Sometimes I need to update one of the field from one participant, I want to update it in a way that when

```
//this data to apply update on the first element of the participants array    
const partialParticipantUpdate = {
        active: false
}
```

can be easily update to the sub document without rewriting all the other property. Basically like findByIdAndUpdate not findByIdAndReplace. I've tried aggregation but its only for reading data not writing data. I've also tried

```
let p = await Project.update({
        "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ee22f90e550c32194fb7a91"),
        "participants._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ee4b5bd4fdcdb0c8813f5f5")
}, { 
        "$set": { "participants.0": partialParticipantUpdate } })
console.log(p);
```

However some of the participants property is removed after the update

```
{
            "_id": { "$oid": "5ee22f90e550c32194fb7a91" },
            "title": "Geo Chart Example",
            "projectId": "myId",
            "company": { "$oid": "5ee22ca46c7fc4358ced20a1" },
            "description": "asd",
            "remark": "re",
            "active": true,
            "participants": [{
                    "_id": { "$oid": "5ee4f37f4d8c234cc02d405a" },
                    "active": false,
                    "timeSpent": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": { "$oid": "5ee4c8a955ed7f23445a3cbc" },
                    "user": { "$oid": "5ee0bdc318998236706b5e5a" },
                    "active": true,
                    "timeSpent": []
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
}
```

The update did change the first participant's "active" property from true to false, but it also lost some of the property like "user" and "timeSpent" array will get emptied as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution

```
const partialParticipantUpdate = {
    active: false
}
let p = await Project.findById("5ee22f90e550c32194fb7a91");
let x = p.participants.id("5ee7224be4e4386084b87d3c");
x.set(partialParticipantUpdate);
let response = await p.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
console.log(response);
```

The only downside is that I have to communicate with mongoose twice